# how to write a where clause in sql query where I need to compare date field with current time?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have three variables
1. Start Date (column in a table)
2. Current Date
3. Start Date + 1 week

I want to write a where clause in  sql query in such a way that

Current Date should be between Start Date and (Start Date + 1 week)
and Current Date can be less than Start Date but 
not greater than (Start Date + 1 week )

Comment: If `CurrentDate` should be between `StartDate` and `StartDate+1week`, and `CurrentDate` can be less than `StartDate`, you are left with only one condition: `CurrentDate` <= `StartDate+1week`

Comment: can I write condition start date >= current date - 1week  as per above logic @HoneyBadger ?

Answer (score 3):

use the `between` function:

```
 where now() between startDate and endDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of

> Current Date should be between Start Date and (Start Date + 1 week)

and

> Current Date can be less than Start Date but not greater than (Start Date + 1 week )

is conflicting, since if currentDate should be between startDate and startDate+ 1week, it will never be less than startDate

If you mean currentDate should be between startDate and startDate+1week write

```
WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `startDate` AND DATE_ADD(`startDate`, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

If you mean currentDate should be less than startDate+1week write

```
WHERE DATE(NOW()) <= DATE_ADD(`startDate`, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```